# What wall materials to use behind glass shower wall?

Tags: bathroom, walls, shower, glass

I am looking to install a glass wall shower system like the one in this video:

https://youtu.be/8-qDda-c6yo

Question is: What should be behind here? They don’t say in video. Should it be some kind of concrete board or is drywall sufficient?

Comment: The manufacturer has a Contact Us link on their web site.  I'm sure they could let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are gluing it to a form of drywall in the video.  I am not sure what the choices are from the manufacturer but I will make two comments.

1. Glass panels are probably hung the same way as big mirrors.   Preferred on drywall and glued.   Why drywall?   It has a little bend in it.   Glass/mirrors have play too.   For instance you would think gluing mirrors on plywood or concrete board would be more secure or easier.   Nothing further from the truth.
2. Love this system.   Glass/Tile-like paneling will be the wave of the future.   The maintenance levels, longevity, water-proofing... this is where it is at.   I have installed some granite sheet showers.   They are great but granite is porous.  This one-ups the granite sheets.   Also these can carefully be taken out if there is an issue.

Coolest shower I have seen in my life was pure glass panels.   The inside of the walls were painted 3 different colors and it was a work of art - used antique plumbing lines.

Answer (score 1):

I have done mirrored walls on Sheetrock back when it was in fashion (70’s).
That looks like fire resistant Sheetrock to me (slightly pink) As long as the seams are well sealed existing Sheetrock will be fine. Water resistant normally green and blue in my area are better than standard Sheetrock. Prior to backer board tiles were commonly glued to Sheetrock in the US and even with all the grout lines this held up for over 20 years and some 40 when the grout was sealed every few years so I don’t see a problem with any wall covering and construction adhesive as long as the Sheetrock / plaster is in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to have be gluing it to plywood.

Glass is heavy so you need something fairly strong,  the screws can easily tear through drywall, and fibre cement is only a little better.